# Where to find when VM was deleted in Virtualbox on Debian

Tags: logging, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox

In which log I can find information about the date of removing the machine ?
I had a virtual machine in Virtualbox, it was deleted, I would like to know when it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such info is stored (in default VBox installation at least)

According to https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html, VM directory contains `Logs` dir, so if whole dir was wiped out, then it's lost I guess.

There are also multiple options like:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBoxMainLogging
Check, maybe some of them were present